# c++ multithreading inside a for loop does not work?

Tags: c++, multithreading

Below is a piece of code using which a function is run over multiple threads once using

(a)

```
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i=i+1)
        multiplicationTask[i] = thread([&] { slice3.push_back(multiParallel(slice1[i], slice2[i])); });
```

and, (b)

```
    multiplicationTask[0] = thread([&] { slice3.push_back(multiParallel(slice1[0], slice2[0])); });
    multiplicationTask[1] = thread([&] { slice3.push_back(multiParallel(slice1[1], slice2[1])); });
    multiplicationTask[2] = thread([&] { slice3.push_back(multiParallel(slice1[2], slice2[2])); });
    multiplicationTask[3] = thread([&] { slice3.push_back(multiParallel(slice1[3], slice2[3])); });
    multiplicationTask[4] = thread([&] { slice3.push_back(multiParallel(slice1[4], slice2[4])); });
```

Both approaches run but the first one returns wrong values. why?

Comment: Unless `push_back` on`slice3` is thread safe, using it this way is incorrect

Answer (score 4):

You are capturing `i` by reference; by the time each thread starts, `i` may have already changed value or may have even gone out of scope. Capture it by value.

In general, you should be very wary of "capture everything by reference" and multithread - unless you know what you are doing, you are probably doing it wrong. Generally in these cases I always specify the capture list explicitly, to make sure I know what I'm capturing and in what way.

Also, as correctly noted by *@LWimsey*, in both cases if `slice3.push_back` is not thread safe (and `push_back` of `std::vector` is not thread safe) what happens is anybody's guess - you may even end up with `slice3` in a completely inconsistent state.

Comment: @VahidGhorbanian: honestly, if you don't have a grasp of capture by value and capture by reference you should really grab a good C++ book and study it before (1) using lambdas and (2) venturing in multithreading.